# MongoDB embedded document distinct and filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b82958518aae6c2d2cd429e"), "troops" : [ { "name" : "Baby Dragon", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Beta Minion", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Bomber", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Boxer Giant", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Cannon Cart", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Night Witch", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Raged Barbarian", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Sneaky Archer", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Archer", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Baby Dragon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Balloon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Barbarian", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Bowler", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Dragon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Giant", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Goblin", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Golem", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Healer", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Hog Rider", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Lava Hound", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Miner", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Minion", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "P.E.K.K.A", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Valkyrie", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Wall Breaker", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Witch", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Wizard", "village" : "home" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b82958518aae6c2d2cd42a1"), "troops" : [ { "name" : "Baby Dragon", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Beta Minion", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Bomber", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Boxer Giant", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Cannon Cart", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Raged Barbarian", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Sneaky Archer", "village" : "builderBase" }, { "name" : "Archer", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Baby Dragon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Balloon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Barbarian", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Bowler", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Dragon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Electro Dragon", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Giant", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Goblin", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Golem", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Healer", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Hog Rider", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Ice Golem", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Lava Hound", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Miner", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Minion", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "P.E.K.K.A", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Valkyrie", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Wall Breaker", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Witch", "village" : "home" }, { "name" : "Wizard", "village" : "home" } ] }
```

and I am trying to get the distinct values from the `home` `troops.village`. The basic (unfiltered) `distinct` returns the expected results (all values from `troops` regardless of `troops.village`):

```
> db.players.distinct("troops.name")
["Archer", "Baby Dragon", "Balloon", "Barbarian", "Beta Minion", "Bomber", "Bowler", "Boxer Giant", "Cannon Cart", "Dragon", "Giant", "Goblin", "Golem", "Healer", "Hog Rider", "Lava Hound", "Miner", "Minion", "Night Witch", "P.E.K.K.A", "Raged Barbarian", "Sneaky Archer", "Valkyrie", "Wall Breaker", "Witch", "Wizard", "Electro Dragon", "Ice Golem", "Battle Blimp", "Drop Ship", "Hog Glider", "Stone Slammer", "Super P.E.K.K.A", "Wall Wrecker", "Yeti", "Siege Barracks"]
```

I've tried the following:

```
> db.players.distinct("troops.name", {"village": "home"})
// This returns an empty set
```

I also tried this:

```
> db.players.distinct("troops.name", {"troops.village": "home"})
// This returns the exact same result set as distinct unfiltered, above.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"query"` part of [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/index.html) is applicable on a document level while you're trying to use it for subdocuments so it won't work in this case. You need to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) to get **distinct, filtered** values within single document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: {
            distinctHomeNames: { $setUnion: { $filter: { input: "$troops", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.village", "home" ] } } } }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cQeAGl7s95D)

EDIT: version with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to print names only [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N_7n230nKfp)

Comment: Wow. What kind of indexes would I need to have in place to make sure that this query is efficient (I already have an index on `troops.name` and `troops.village`).

Comment: @EricLindsey not sure if indexes will make any difference here. What you're doing is actually projection, not filtering when indexes are mostly applicable. You can try to create an index on `troops.village` to see if it makes any difference

Comment: That makes sense. In that case, is there a way to filter *then* distinct? Obviously I could roll my own code to do this, just wondering if there's a builtin solution.

Comment: @EricLindsey in your example you're running `.find({})` which means that you want to retrieve all the documents from your collection. That's querying part where indexes are really important. Then we're just running `$filter` which gets executed on every document so it's rather reshaping than querying. Obviously the nested array gets filtered before distinct (`$setUntion`) gets executed. Hope it helps

Comment: Your version with `$map` looks promising but is not quite what I was expecting. It returns one result document for every source document. How would I merge and distinct those documents? Given the configuration at https://mongoplayground.net/p/R6N2_iz7GNO how can I get one single result document that contains all the home names exactly once?

Comment: @EricLindsey you need to get all of them into one doc - `$group` by `null` and then use `$setUnion` one more time: https://mongoplayground.net/p/h-Jgw-dF1fw